# AWS ACM certificate not covering verified (sub)domain, only Lambda domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, certificate, aws-api-gateway

I've created an AWS Lambda function and want to point a subdomain of mine to it. My domain is registered at DNSimple, where I've pointed the nameservers to my hosting provider, Siteground. I've added a CNAME record in Siteground to point sub.example.com to AWS Lambda, i.e. `abcdefg.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`.

So as far as I understand:

DNSimple -> Siteground -> AWS Lambda

When I navigate to sub.example.com, I actually get to see my site, but the browser marks it as insecure. When I inspect the certificate, I see it is issued for the amazonaws domain:

[image: SSL Certificate]

However, if I check in the AWS console:

[image: AWS Console]

The blurred parts are my sub.example.com domain, so I would think there is a certificate for this (sub)domain. I let AWS verify that I own the domain by adding a DNS record (CNAME) as requested.

For completeness, I've added a screenshot of my custom domain in API Gateway:

[image: API Gateway]

The correct certificate is being used.

So what am I doing wrong here? Why does the certificate issued by AWS not cover my (sub)domain?